# Circuit Board Troubleshooting

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly, troubleshooting

The question is: "Where can I get circuit boards tested or troubleshot?"

As My profile shows, I am not an EE, but I'm forced to play one at my company. The following is just some background information which may or may not be useful. The question is singular.

I had about 100 small boards made by an assembly company, I believe they are, and 15 of them did not work.  The assembly company does not have the abilities to test them.  They failed to load the firmware, "Failed to Autobaud" error message on the firmware loader.  Not having any real experience in this field, I figured 15% failure is high.  Two other boards they made for me at the same time, were 100% good.  This board is a bit more complex, but the gentleman who designed them for us had several hundred made over the years, in China and Taiwan when he went there to visit family.  Turns out he ordered extra and he repaired the bad boards before we ever saw them, so we had 100% good boards.  I don't believe there is anything in the drawings or BOM that would be the issue, it's been well tested.

So, is it worth trying to run down the issues, or just accept the 15% failure rate?  This was the very first batch we had these people make.  They seem to be good people and very helpful, they just do not have the ability to troubleshoot the boards.

I would appreciate any help.  I did read on another older thread here that bad boards are basically a given.  I guess I was spoiled by getting 100% good boards all of these years.

Comment: Basically you are looking a service or to hire a paid consultant to work for you?

Comment: "is it worth trying to run down the issues..."  Depends on what these boards cost, how many more you'll need and what your cost is for possible design changes when you find issues. And nowadays, also depends on whether you can find more chips to make more boards !!

Comment: Thanks, and yes I'm looking for someone that can troubleshoot these bad boards.  The boards are <$100 each.  I have 15 boards.  The main thing I'm looking for is to see what the issue is more than fixing the boards.  I believe the parts are good.  They all come from DigiKey and Mouser.  I cannot have any design changes unless they are minor one.  This is an FDA approved machine and I really am limited to the changes I can make.  But, the design is good and has been in use for nearly 10 years.  It's that I'm having to have them made now, and I'm a novice at best.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have defective PCBs, faults in assembly, or faulty components? Are any/all of these being checked for by your vendor(s)?

That your engineer friend ordered extra boards and/or repaired bad boards suggests that the fault was in assembly (you can't really repair a bare PCB that failed electrical testing). Can you not consult with him to determine the nature of the repairs he did?

Taking a step back, the process of getting boards made can be incredibly complex.

1. The bare PCB can be complex enough with its copper and dielectric layers, drilled holes and routing, etc. Depending on tolerances and feature sizes, this can be the first step where problems arise. The fabricator will usually offer you options to test the boards (electrical tests) and give you the option of whether you can only accept panels where all boards passed the test, or the option to accept "X-out" boards, where one or more PCBs are marked as failed in a given panel. Omitting these tests saves money, but depending on the quality and reputation of the fabricator could cost you more money in the long run.
2. The PCB assembler (PCBA) may or may not be the same company, but is the one who physically attaches components to the board. This could range from an individual doing everything manually to an enormous company with vast numbers of operations and equipment. You should check if your PCBA has quality checks in place like solder paste inspection, automatic optical inspection (AOI), x-ray, etc. to verify that solder and components are placed correctly. A simple rotated or misaligned component, tombstoned resistor, or voids in solder pads could result in an assembled board that fails.
3. If manufacturing goes well, but boards still fail, it could be the result of damaged or counterfeit components. Does the PCBA take precautions to avoid accumulating moisture in components? Are you sure your components are genuine? Do they offer functional testing?

You may not have been involved in selecting the vendors and arranging (or waiving) quality checks, but you should check into these steps as much as you can.

Having a couple of boards made can yield good results (your 100% experience), because they may more likely involve human inspection and care. When you scale up to mass production, especially if the company doesn't have checks in place, can result in high failure rates.

Even the design of the PCB itself (orientation of components, thermal relief on pads, etc.) can affect whether it is more or less likely to have components seat correctly during solder reflow and so forth. Having only a few boards made will more likely involve manual labor and inspection, but when quantity is scaled up, design details become more important as do automated tests and inspections.

The nature of this site is to not provide specific recommendations of manufacturers or vendors, but instead to help provide information that will help you know what to ask or look for. I recommend you look for another PCBA, if only just to troubleshoot and review the boards you already have. You may find that their capabilities and information are better than the one you're using. PCBA companies will generally offer some sort of engineering assistance and advice in an effort to win your business. Don't forget to check companies in your country as well. Although they may be more expensive, they tend to offer additional assistance and engineering to better compete with low-cost board houses.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  There is no way I can answer much of that.  No, the man who designed it and had previous boards made is no longer available.  It's all on me now.  As to your #1, All I know is that they are an assembly shop.  They do some type of testing, but i don't know what.  As far as I could tell this shop is well respected, but it's my first venture into all of this.  I have another friend who has helped me some.  He is a PhD in Computer Engineering.  He looked over the files and cleaned up some things and helped me find these guys.

Comment: @Joepiccaso - Hi, Your [2nd comment above](/posts/comments/1527538) partially repeats your [1st comment](/posts/comments/1527532), and also seems to be missing a negative, since you say "*Unfortunately I picked [one] that does have an engineering dept*" but I think we've established from your 1st comment, that they *don't* have an engineering department who can assist with your questions. So your 2nd comment (i.e. the one just above this one) has confused me. Do you want to delete it and have another go? Or did you really mean the partial duplication etc?

Comment: I apologize .  This is my first time, and I didn't realize the word limitation on responses and tried to make a new paragraph by using the return key, which actually sent it.  Then I couldn't find my response, so I thought it was gone, thus the double response.  And, yes, the current shop doesn't have engineers to trouble shoot.  I was looking for help determining if it made sense to even do that. And, I did realize that this isn't a sight for vendor recommendations, but was hoping for some guidance in location a shop that id troubleshooting, if any. I apologize.  Joe

Comment: @Joepiccaso - Hi, Briefly: (a) Yes, comments (which are meant to be short) can't contain line breaks & pressing Enter submits the comment. However they can be deleted and replaced, if you wanted. (b) As you now know, it's off-topic here to try to find local vendors :-( This site tries to build up Q&A of long-term value, and such recommendations (as with any shopping) get obsolete too quickly to be useful long-term. (c) If you were trying to do the troubleshooting yourself and supplied schematics, photos, scope traces etc, that would be on-topic. Otherwise, this site likely can't help :-( Sorry

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  As I said above, I did understand that this wasn't a forum to locate specific vendors, but wanting some advice on where to look.  I understand all of the issues that can go wrong, I'm seeking help on how to fix it.  I cannot fix what I do not know.  And, I know very little.  And, I'm getting the distinct feeling that I'm just on the wrong place not being an engineer.  I just read an old thread from a Google search from this site and it was helpful.  I thought I would give it a try.  I did give a lot of background info and thought it would help.  Thank you.